# Moosend API for new subscribers in django

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I tried to follow this tutorial to create new subscriber in Moosend from my django app .

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
values = """

{
"Name": "Paul",
"Email": "someEmail@email.com",
"HasExternalDoubleOptIn": false,
"CustomFields": [
  "Age=25",
  "Country=USA"
]
}"""
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json'
}
request = Request('https://api.moosend.com/v3/subscribers/7cfad3edfd9ad-07d7-4c51-810e-74e27sdsf8505c2e/subscribe.json?apikey=77f6s34dfd8914-4e3c-4d61-8435-9346f5b4adf6&New%20item=', data=values, headers=headers)
response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print response_body
```

That code WORKS IN python 2 TO CREATE new subscriber in maling list i have made some changes so that it should work in python3 but still it is still it is not inserting new subscribers on my mailing list in Moossend

changes done to work in python 3 that i have done

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

request2 = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.moosend.com/v3/subscribers/7cfad3edfd9ad-07d7-4c51-810e-74e27sdsf8505c2e/subscribe.json?apikey=77f6s34dfd8914-4e3c-4d61-8435-9346f5b4adf6&New%20item=', data=values, headers=headers)

response_body = request2.read()
                    print(response_body)
```

Need help in creating new subscriber for using python3 on my Moonsend mailing list

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" What error/response do you get?

Comment: no error comes up i even and an exception . it does not even add new subscriber to my mailing list

Comment: Thanks i have managed to fix .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the updated code if you are using python3.5 that works and manage to add new subscriber to Moosend mailing list:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import Request
import urllib.parse 

values = """

{
"Name": "Paul",
"Email": "someEmail@email.com",
"HasExternalDoubleOptIn": false,
"CustomFields": [
"Age=25",
"Country=USA"
]
}"""
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json'
}
data = values.encode()
req = Request('https://api.moosend.com/v3/subscribers/7cfad3edfd9ad-07d7-4c51-810e-74e27sdsf8505c2e/subscribe.json?apikey=77f6s34dfd8914-4e3c-4d61-8435-9346f5b4adf6&New%20item=', data=values, headers=headers)
response_body  = urlopen(req).read()  
print(response_body)
```